# Determining unique usage in a Pandas array

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a large dataset (1M+ rows, and 50 columns). I've created a fake dataset below to highlight my issue.   I'm trying to determine the parts that are used ONLY used on `Ford` OR `VW` (and not on other car brands), but am not sure how to approach this.

In reality, I have about 500 'car brands', and may want to look for 30+ of these, therefore if I can search by isin(list), that would be perfect.

```
data = { 'part': ['A','A','B','B','B','C','C','D','D','D','D','E','F','F','G'],'make':  ['VW','Ford','VW','Nissan','Ford','VW','Nissan','Ford','Mazda','VW','Ford','VW','Ford','Mazda','Ford'],}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

For `Ford` or `VW`, the result should be `A`,`E` and `G`.  (As `A` has only `Ford` and `VW`, and `E`  has only `VW`, and `G` has only `Ford`)

Comment: `np.unique(df.loc[df.make.isin(["VW","Ford"]),["part"]].values)` results in `array(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], dtype=object)`

Comment: Rob, but B,C,D and F also contain other car brands, therefore are not uniqe to Ford or VW - Dataframe just edited based on prior comment as well to add G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CODE:**

```
make = ['Ford', 'VW']
mask = df['make'].isin(make).groupby(df['part']).all()
parts = mask[mask].index
```

**DETAILS:**

Create a boolean mask using `Series.isin` which represent the condition where the column `make` contains the brands from the predefined `make` list:

```
>>> df['make'].isin(make)

0      True
1      True
2      True
3     False
4      True
5      True
6     False
7      True
8     False
9      True
10     True
11     True
12     True
13    False
14     True
Name: make, dtype: bool
```

Group the above boolean mask on column `part` and aggregate using `all` to create a new boolean mask representing the condition where all the boolean values in the above mask are `True` per `part`:

```
>>> mask

part
A     True
B    False
C    False
D    False
E     True
F    False
G     True
Name: make, dtype: bool
```

Finally use boolean indexing to filter out the `index` values in the above boolean mask to get the list of `parts` that are only used by the `brands` in the predefined `make` list:

```
>>> parts

Index(['A', 'E', 'G'], dtype='object', name='part')
```

Answer (score 0):

- for efficiency, calculate mask once
- get list of parts used in **Ford** or **VW**
- get list of parts used in other makes
- finally a mask to get required parts

```
data = {'part': ['A','A','B','B','B','C','C','D','D','D','D','E','F','F'],'make': 
['VW','Ford','VW','Nissan','Ford','VW','Nissan','Ford','Mazda','VW','Ford','VW','Ford','Mazda'],}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

mask = df.make.isin(["VW","Ford"])
used = np.unique(df.loc[mask,["part"]])
otherused = np.unique(df.loc[~mask,["part"]])

pd.Series(used)[lambda s: ~s.isin(otherused)]
```

### output

```
0    A
4    E
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```py
# parts used for only one make
part_usage = df.assign(grouped_make = lambda x: x['make'].replace({'VW': 'custom_make', 'Ford': 'custom_make'})).groupby('part')['grouped_make'].nunique()

part_usage = part_usage[part_usage.eq(1)]

print(part_usage.index)
```